# CSS en Table View - JAVAFX

Tags: java, css, javafx, table, scenebuilder

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desarrollando un proyecto con JavaFx, incluyendo CSS me he dado cuenta que al final de una `TableView` se presenta este recuadro gris, cuando hago uso del *scroll*. Y no he logrado cambiar el color de este recuadro.
¿Cómo puedo cambiarle el color?.

Answer (score -1):

El selector es: `.filler` . es una región que está por defecto si  no hay ninguna columna y se hace visible cuando `TableView` necesita añadir un `ScrollBar`

```
.table-view .filler{
   -fx-background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: lo sabes por experiencia o sabes donde esta documentado?

Comment: De hecho es relevante: [Te he votado negativamente porque es solamente código.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/)

Comment: Es solamente código. ¿Qué hace el selector? Lee [answer].